# How to accomplish evaluating record results in SQL without the use of a cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements

I would first just like it known I have spent days looking for this answer before asking I know you guys are awesome and your time is valuable.  On to my problem.

I have a very large query pulling out a summed value of a column.  This summed value needs to be used to determine an update to a separate table/column which is actually something I could do with a cursor only my boss has asked me to find a way to accomplish this without one.

So let me give this example.

If the summed value is lets say > than A but less than Z then I need to make an insert of the summed value and the corresponding medical code from my look up table for that value into the final table.  There are actually over a dozen compares but here is the part that is tricking me up.  If it matches a compare it is to STOP further compares down the hierarchy and take the very first condition even if it matches ones further down the line.  So a record could match 4 of the 12 possibilities but it needs to stop the evaluation at the first one and make the insert.

Also bear in mind that I am dealing with records in the millions so efficiency is paramount when executing this nightly update.

Any Ideas would be appreciated!!

I AM adding this information in an effort to help clarify my scenario:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 SUM(CAST(PPC.[UserDefinedString1] AS INT)), PD.PpdID, SUM(somethingelse) AS rtcharge1, SUM(somethingelse1) AS rcharge2, PA1.DType
FROM PatientData PD
JOIN PatientAux1 PA1 
ON PD.ppdID = PA1.PpdID
JOIN [dbo].[PatientProcedureCosts] PPC 
ON PD.PpdID = PPC.PpdID
WHERE PD.PatientTypeID = 'O'
GROUP BY PD.PpdID
```

Results would look like

```
 A         B            C    D    E
945, 47896jhrf89721    900  45  CHEMO

IF A is >50 but <950 and DType is Chemo
```

DO THIS (insert some values of a subquery into a lookup table)

```
IF (rtcharge1 + rtcharge2)<950 and Dtype is Chemo
```

DO THIS(another insert from a subquery)

more and more IF's but the point is it matched both of the IF's above only it never should check the second if because the insert from the first if was done.

Comment: May be CASE may be CROSS APPLY . Or MERGE. Can you share DDL and sample data?

Comment: Let me work on deidentifying the records and get some examples for you in real life but I did play with the CASE function but I couldnt crack how to get it to perform an insert it appears to me to only update a specified column.

Comment: Would the OUTPUT clause help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: I wonder if you could use COALESCE? If your matching condition could be a NULL if it fails but something else if it succeeds it would just grab the first one that wasn't NULL?

Comment: Give specific column names with sample input and desired output.

Comment: I apologize I am frantically putting together an example query and including as much of the data as I can.  Please give me just a little longer I see my question was lacking examples.

Comment: Updated with Code sample

Comment: Does all inserts go to the same lookup table or they target  different lookup tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement this using SSIS, Conditional Split Transformaton will provide required behavior
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137886.aspx

Comment: I am looking into this now.  I have used those items in SSIS packages and if I can make 13 conditions I will be set but I have never coded them long hand only used the GUI. If this works I will bow to you sir.

Comment: This is in SSIS I need to use a stored proc for this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on too little information, I would **guess** this could be resolved with judicious use of a ranking function, probably `row_number()`. Leading question for this: if you match 4 out of 12 items but must only process the first, how is that "first" item identified? Randomly, or is there some algorithm? (This is the kind of situation `row_number()` excels at...)

Comment: I have a list provided of the match Hierarchy it looks like this:

1.        Radiation Therapy/Infusion/Chemo/Oncology:  Radiation Therapy/Infusion/Chemo/Oncology cases where operating room (rctchg40)<drugs (rctchg67) OR operating room (rctchg40)< radiation (rctchg45+rctchg 46)

2.        Emergency Department: Emergency Department cases where emergency, free standing center (rctchg34), or Trauma Resuscitation rate center charges (rctchg90) > 0

3.        Drug: Drug cases where eapgs are assigned to drug service line

Comment: Just know that its a long list and it could potentially match multiple items but the list as provided is in a ranked order of 1-13 and I can code the checks I am just looking for a scenario of how to accomplish not so much as here is the data do it for me.  I am a learner more than a cannibalist.

Comment: This should really be put in the body of your question, where (important!) it can be properly formatted and made legible.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to split this into multiple queries performed in a backwards manner so it will start at 13 and move up stopping at the highest match this should accomplish what I need.  I appreciate the questions and attempts to help!